# Powershell - Rename filename by removing the last few characters

Tags: powershell

I want to remove the last 11 characters of multiple files names. For example
I have these file names:

```
ABCDE_2015_10_20
HIJKL_2015_10_20
MNOPQ_2015_10_20
RSTUV_2015_10_20
```

would like to rename them to

```
ABCDE
HIJKL
MNOPQ
RSTUV
```

I have tried using the follwing code:

```
Get-ChildItem 'E:\Thomson Reuters\Stage' | rename-item -newname { [string]($_.name).substring($_.name.length -14) }
```

Can anybody tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: And have you made any attempt to solve this yourself?

Comment: Yes - i can remove the characters from the start of the filename but not the last using the following:  Get-ChildItem 'E:\Thomson Reuters\Stage' | rename-item -newname { [string]($_.name).substring($_.name.length -14) }

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33255834/edit) the question and update it with the code you wrote so far then

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're almost there, you just need to tell `substring` exactly where to start and end:

```
Get-ChildItem 'E:\Thomson Reuters\Stage' | rename-item -newname { $_.name.substring(0,$_.name.length-11) }
```

By passing two integers to `substring` you give it the StartIndex and Length of the string you want to capture. [See here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx) for the documentation

Answer (score 12):

Just to add to the response from [arco444](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3115685/arco444):

```
Get-ChildItem 'E:\Thomson Reuters\Stage' -filter *.txt | rename-item -NewName {$_.name.substring(0,$_.BaseName.length-6) + $_.Extension -replace "_"," "}
```

This would rename all .txt files in the directory, remove the last 6 characters of the file name, replace any remaining underscore in the filename with a space but still retain the file extension.

So assuming these were text files you would see something like this:

```
ABCDE_2015_10_20.txt
HIJKL_2015_10_20.txt
MNOPQ_2015_10_20.txt
RSTUV_2015_10_20.txt
```

Become this:

```
ABCDE 2015.txt
HIJKL 2015.txt
MNOPQ 2015.txt
RSTUV 2015.txt
```

Answer (score 5):

As you want to `split` the file name at the 1st underscore,

- use the `.split()` method or `-split` operator with the zero based index `[0]`.
- rename changing the `BaseName` and keeping the `Extension`

---

```
Get-ChildItem 'E:\Thomson Reuters\Stage' |  
    Rename-Item -NewName { $_.BaseName.Split('_')[0] + $_.Extension }
```