# Powershell Remove Text Between before the file extension and an underscore

Tags: powershell

I have a few hundered PDF files that have text in their file names which need to be removed. Each of the file names have several underscores in their names depending on how long the file name is. My goal is to remove the text in that exists between the `.pdf` file extension and the last `_`.

For example I have:

- AB_NAME_NAME_NAME_NAME_DS_123_EN**_6**.pdf
- AC_NAME_NAME_NAME_DS_321_EN**_10**.pdf
- AD_NAME_NAME_DS_321_EN**_101**.pdf

And would like the bold part to be removed to become:

- AB_NAME_NAME_NAME_NAME_DS_123_EN.pdf
- AC_NAME_NAME_NAME_DS_321_EN.pdf
- AD_NAME_NAME_DS_321_EN.pdf

I am a novice at powershell but I have done some research and have found [Powershell - Rename filename by removing the last few characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33255834/powershell-rename-filename-by-removing-the-last-few-characters) question helpful but it doesnt get me exactly what I need because I cannot hardcode the length of characters to be removed because they may different lengths (2-4)

`Get-ChildItem 'C:\Path\here' -filter *.pdf | rename-item -NewName {$_.name.substring(0,$_.BaseName.length-3) + $_.Extension}`

It seems like there may be a way to do this using `.split` or `regex` but I was not able to find a solution. Thanks.

Comment: Try `$_.BaseName.substring(0,$_.BaseName.lastindexof('_'))`

Comment: Or `$_.Name -replace '(_[a-z0-9]+)(?=\.pdf)'`

Comment: @TheMadTechnician that was it! It makes sense. Go ahead and put your answer down so you can get the points. I ended up with `{ $_.BaseName.substring(0,$_.BaseName.lastindexof('_')) + $_.Extension }`

Comment: @Olaf your regex version takes away the `.pdf` file extension (unless I am implementing it incorrectly?)

Comment: @crazymatt, it works as expected here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `LastIndexOf()` method of the `[string]` class to get the index of the last instance of a character. In your case this should do it:

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\Path\here' -filter *.pdf | rename-item -NewName { $_.BaseName.substring(0,$_.BaseName.lastindexof('_')) + $_.Extension }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the [`-replace` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375) with a [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions) enables a concise solution:

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\Path\here' -Filter *.pdf | 
  Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '_[^_]+(?=\.)' } -WhatIf
```

<sup>`-WhatIf` *previews* the renaming operation. Remove it to perform actual renaming.</sup>

- `_[^_]+` matches a `_` character followed by one or more non-`_` characters (`[^-]`)

  - If you wanted to match more specifically by (decimal) *digits* only (`\d`), use `_\d+` instead.
- `(?=\.)` is a [look-ahead assertion](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (`(?=...)`) that matches a literal `.` (`\.`), i.e., the start of the filename extension *without including it in the match*.
- By not providing a replacement operand to `-replace`, it is implicitly the *empty string* that replaces what was matched, which effectively removes the last `_`-prefixed token before the filename extension.

---

You can **make the regex more robust** by also **handling file names with "double" extensions**; e.g., the above solution would replace filename `a_bc.d_ef.pdf` with `a.c.pdf`, i.e., perform *two* replacements. To prevent that, use the following regex instead:

```
$_.Name -replace '_[^_]+(?=\.[^.]+$)'
```

The look-ahead assertion now ensures that only the *last* extension matches: a literal `.` (`\.`) followed by one or more (`+`) characters *other* than literal `.` (`[^.]`, a negated character set (`[^...]`)) at the *end* of the string (`$`).

Comment: While this meets OPs expressed requirements a more safe RE would IMO be `Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '_[^_]+(?=\.pdf$)' } -WhatIf` or `Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace "_[^_]+(?=$($_.Extension)$)" } -WhatIf`

Comment: Fair point, @LotPings, but I wanted to keep the solution short. Assuming that the input file names contain only _one_ `.` char - as in the sample file names - allowed me to do that. Please see my update for a solution that also handles multiple `.` instances correctly while still avoiding the need to repeat the input extension.

Answer (score 0):

Just to show another alternative,

- the part to remove from the `Name` is the **last** element from the `BaseName` splitted with `_`
- which is a negative index from the split `[-1]`

```
    Get-ChildItem 'C:\Path\here' -Filter *.pdf |%{$_.BaseName.split('_\d+')[-1]}
    6
    10
    101
```

- as the split removes the `_` it has to be applied again to remove it.

---

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\Path\here' -Filter *.pdf | 
   Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '_'+$_.BaseName.split('_')[-1] } -whatif
```

**EDIT** a modified variant which splits the BaseName at the underscore
without removing the splitting character is using the `-split` operator and
a RegEx with a [zero length lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```
> Get-ChildItem 'C:\Path\here' -Filter *.pdf |%{($_.BaseName -split'(?=_\d+)')[-1]}
_6
_10
_101
```

---

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\Path\here' -Filter *.pdf | 
    Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace ($_.BaseName -split'(?=_)')[-1] } -whatif
```

Comment: Thanks for adding this. I had been trying to get this to work originally using `BaseName.split('_')[-1]` but wasnt having much luck. I will test this one as well

Comment: See the last, even simpler and  more concise variant as it removes only trailing digits, so it can be run repeatedly without removing nonumeric parts.